# Write New element in XML file using c#

Tags: c#

I have IIS config file which is written in XML. I want to add a new element in that file using c#. I have used a few more methods but it was not useful.

```
     <configuration>
     <system.applicationHost>
        <sites>
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" 
                physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" 
              sslFlags="0" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="test" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="test">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\vcsites\test" 
                />
            </application>
            <bindings>             

                "I WANT TO ADD NEW BINDING ELEMENT HERE"

                <binding protocol="http"  
                    bindingInformation="*:80:test.omnibiz.com" />
                <binding protocol="https"  
                    bindingInformation="*:443:test.omnibiz.com" 
            sslFlags="1" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
      </sites>
   </system.applicationHost>
  </configuration>
```

This the C# code that I have tried. but this is not working. it's not giving me any error but I guess I am missing something.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\applicationHost.xml");

        XElement NewEelement = new XElement("binding", new 
        XAttribute("protocol", "http"), new 
        XAttribute("bindingInformation", 
            "*:80:newtest.omnibiz.com"));

        doc.Element("configuration")
           .Element("system.applicationHost")
           .Element("sites")
           .Elements("site")
           .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "2")
           .Elements("bindings").FirstOrDefault()
        .Add(NewEelement);


      doc.Save(@"D:\applicationHost.xml",SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
    }
```

In the end it should look like this. I have a new binding element inside bindings tags.

```
         <site name="test" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="test">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\vcsites\test" 
                 />
            </application>
            <bindings>             
                <binding protocol="http" 
           bindingInformation="*:80:newtest.omnibiz.com" /> 
                <binding protocol="http" 
             bindingInformation="*:80:test.omnibiz.com" />
                <binding protocol="https" 
          bindingInformation="*:443:test.omnibiz.com" sslFlags="1" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Comment: Just curious, is this something that web config transforms could help with?

Comment: Instead of `Add`, use `AddFirst` instead.

Comment: Consider using [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager) to manipulate it so you know you're making the right changes.